# GGplot averages bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a bar graph with error bars in ggplot. I have columns with species marked as present or absent, P or A, and another column with percent damage. I would like a graph with the all the species on the x-axis as present or absent and the average percent when that species is present or absent in the y-axis.

Example data

````
example$species1 = c('P','P','P','P','P','A','A','A','A','A')
example$species2 = c('P','P','A','A','P','P','A','A','P','P')
example$percent1 = c(10,20,15,21,13,50,75,60,35,44)
View(example)```
````

Comment: The data doesn't line up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the plot of the average of presence or absence per species, you can reshape your dataframe into a longer format using for example `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` and then calculate the mean and sem of the percentage of each categories per species as follow:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
EX <- example %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(species1,species2), names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>%
  group_by(var,val) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(percent1),
                                  SEM = sd(percent1)/sqrt(n()))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   var [2]
  var      val    Mean   SEM
  <chr>    <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 species1 A      52.8  6.88
2 species1 P      15.8  2.08
3 species2 A      42.8 14.7 
4 species2 P      28.7  6.83
```

Then, you can plot this new dataframe using `ggplot` as follow:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(EX, aes(x = var, y = Mean, fill = val))+
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean-SEM, ymax = Mean+SEM), position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.2)+
  labs(x = "Species", y = "Percentage")
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

**Reproducible example**

```r
example = data.frame(species1 =  c('P','P','P','P','P','A','A','A','A','A'),
                     species2 = c('P','P','A','A','P','P','A','A','P','P'),
                     percent1 =  c(10,20,15,21,13,50,75,60,35,44))
```